# What Types of Models can be used to scientifically approach frontend development?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, frontend, model-driven-development

In my experience Frontend developmemt mostly consists of jumping in and developing in an extreme programming or very agile way. Although in my bachelors thesis I will have to do the architecture and development of an SaaS-Frontend and use the waterfall model to do so (Analysing requirements, making broad Modelling/Planning, making detailed Models, Implementing, Testing, Integration).
For databases and object oriented backends models such as UML Class Diagrams and ERMs are common for the upfront planning of the architecture.

**What types of models can be used to do the architecture of a component based frontend like React.js?**